# cmd to change Java settings

Tags: windows, proxy, java, script, batch

Is there a way to have a `cmd` add an exception to the proxies in Java?
*(Control panel > Network settings > Advanced nework settings)*

It should be something a user can double-click or wrapped in a logon-script.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with PAC files? You can find a lot of examples on Google, and you can use like this:
"Use automatic proxy configuration file"

Script location: file:///c:/users/bacsog/desktop/proxy.pac

Example:

http://www.findproxyforurl.com/pac_file_examples.html

Comment: That means I will still have to do a manual action to do the setup?